# HTML pushstate on A Tag to change parameter, load twice

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change parameter without refreshing. So, I am now using pushstate. Like this,

**HTML**

```
<a class="filter" data-value="recent" href="#">Recent</a>
<a class="filter" data-value="popular" href="#">Popular</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('value');

    if ( data == 'recent' ) {
        // make new_params_string here
        history.pushState({}, "", window.location.pathname + '?' + new_params_string);
    } else if ( data == 'popular' ) {
        // make new_params_string here
        history.pushState({}, "", window.location.pathname + '?' + new_params_string);
    }
});
```

It work nicely but, it load page 2 times. So, I get duplicated call javascript. And, it make my site terrible.

What is the wrong point in my logic?

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @Lee I add e.preventDefault() on click listener. It change parameter but, do not call javascript. I want to call javascript once, after change parameter.

Comment: You're also missing a `);` from the end of your click handler.

Comment: It works for me, maybe it's a bug in related code? http://output.jsbin.com/sudiyo

Comment: @Lee That is my mistake to re-write from code to here. I edit that.

Comment: @Lee Does not pushstate refresh any information about new parameters? Your code just change parameters. I think that change parameter using pushstate than to get new information with javascript.